# GRUB error: unknown filesystem

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, lvm, grub, luks

I am trying to setup lvm on luks2 with boot inside lvm.

```
NAME                 FSTYPE       FSVER      FSAVAIL    FSUSE%  MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1
├─nvme0n1p1          vfat         FAT32      510.7M     0%      /mnt/efi
└─nvme0n1p2          crypto_LUKS  2
  └─cryptlvm         LVM2_member  LVM2 001
    ├─ArchNVMe-swap  swap         1                             [SWAP]
    ├─ArchNVMe-root  ext4         1.0        27G        8%      /mnt
    └─ArchNVMe-home  ext4         1.0        395.5G     0%      /mnt/home
```

`cryptomount` works, and `ls` in grub rescue shows all the volumes, but it can't identify their filesystem (`error: unknown filesystem`), including `ArchNVMe-root` and `nvme0n1p2`. On wiki it says that it can happen if BIOS boot partition outside of the first 2TiB. But I didn't create BIOS boot partition because it also says that UEFI systems don't need one. I have tried with BIOS boot partition, it didn't change anything, still getting that error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have GRUB's `ext2.mod` module loaded, or included in the main `grubx64.efi` binary? If you have Secure Boot enabled, it will allow loading of executable code only from signed UEFI/Windows PE binary formatted files... and GRUB uses the ELF binary format for its modules, so dynamic loading of GRUB modules is blocked by Secure Boot. The main `grubx64.efi` will be a UEFI/Windows PE-formatted binary so it can be signed to satisfy Secure Boot, but the modules can't be.

Comment: BIOS boot partition is only needed if you want to use the legacy BIOS version of GRUB, that is, GRUB architecture `i386-pc`. It is impossible to install a `i386-pc` GRUB to a GPT-partitioned disk without creating a BIOS boot partition first, so you probably have a native UEFI GRUB, i.e. GRUB architecture `x86_64-efi`, and it does not need the BIOS boot partition at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [telcoM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/258991/telcom) for their comment -- it appears that I didn't have `ext2.mod` loaded.